# Passing object by value to a SubClass constructor leading to SuperClass's constructor not call

Tags: c++

I was trying to implement a SuperClass "Person" and inheriting from it some SubClasses.
The SubClass's constructor is passed an object from "Person" type and then calls parent contractor with object's member as passed value.
Everything is OK if pass the object to SubClass constructor by reference but, if pass the object by value then something strange happens. The SubClass object will create but not through the parent constructor (just a copy of the passed object will create and destroys after constructor ends.)

```
class Person
{
private:
    string _name;

public:
    Person (string name) : _name(name){cout << "Person registered.\n";}
    ~Person () {cout << "deleted\n";}
    string getName() {return _name;}
};

class Employee : public Person
{
public:
    Employee (Person p) : Person(p.getName()){};
};

int main()
{
    Person a("Jack");
    Employee b(a);
    cout << a.getName() << "\n";
    cout << b.getName() << "\n";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected creation of 3 objects and destruction of one, but 2 objects were created and one was destroyed.

Expected output:

```
Person registered.
Person registered.
Person registered.
deleted
Jack
Jack
```

Actual output:

```
Person registered.
Person registered.
deleted
Jack
Jack
```

And as output shows, second object is created but not through constructor.

Any idea of how SubClass object creates?

Comment: Since you pass the `Person` object *by value* to the `Employee` constructor, it will be *copied* and the copy-constructor of `Person` will be invoked (unless elided).

Comment: Also note that because the `Person` destructor is not `virtual`, it will not be invoked when the `Employee` object is destructed.

Comment: You should have at least as many **deleted** than constructor calls… but the extra **deleted** would be print when you exit the scope of **main**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a class (or a struct), the compiler implicitly generates several functions (e.g. default constructor, destructor, copy-/move- constructor, and copy-/move- assignment operators, etc.) for you, depending on context (i.e. whether or not you yourself have defined one of those functions).

Here, when you pass the `Person` object `a` by value to the Employee object `b`, the compiler calls on the implicitly generated copy constructor, which basically is this:

```cpp
Person (const Person& p) : _name(p._name) { /* add logging */ }
```

The implicitly-generated copy constructor's job is to call the copy constructors of all of the members of the class.

If you define the copy constructor yourself with a logging message, you will see that it's the 3 constructions and 1 destruction you expected, but one of the constructions was by copy as the compiler won't be able to copy-elide because its parameter is not a `prvalue`.

**Note**: the compiler can sometimes elide (i.e. choose not to perform in the first place) the copy constructor call and instead instantiate the to-be-copied object in place as an optimization. This means that user-defined copy constructors should never have any side effects.

Comment: Rather `Person (const Person& p) : _name(p._name)` – while equivalent in *given* case, the getter *might* do additional things that won't be executed on copy-constructing!